# Compiles via command line but not in ant

Tags: java, ant, compilation, terminal

My Java project compiles via Terminal (using Mac OSX 10.8), but not in Ant 1.9.1. I've been trying to distill these three lines of code into a valid Ant build script. The line is:

```
javac -cp "./:./ij.jar:ij-ImageIO_.jar:flanagan.jar" org/rhwlab/image/ImageWindow.java
```

However, I have been trying to write an Ant build script that can perform this process efficiently (the following):

```
    <target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}"
        compiler="javac1.6" classpathref="classpath">
         <include name="org/rhwlab/image/ImageWindow.java"/>
         </javac>
     </target>
```

But errors arise as follows:

```
 Image3D2Z.java:9: package gov.noaa.pmel.sgt does not exist
 Analysis2.java:11: package gov.noaa.pmel.sgt.dm does not exist
```

How can I get my project to compile via Ant?

Comment: How is defined the `classpath` in your Ant build ?

Comment: classpath is: 
    <path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
    </path>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a classpath problem. Try something like:

```
<path id="myclasspath">
  <fileset dir="${dir.path}">
    <include name="*.jar"/>
  </fileset>
</path>
...

<javac destdir="${build.dir}">
  <src path="${src.dir}"/>
  <classpath refid="myclasspath"/>
</javac>
```

Comment: classpath is 
    <path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
    </path>

Comment: I think the classpath and libraries are fine -- I don't understand why this package works via commandline but not in Ant

Comment: `echo` and check if classpath is indeed right. If it is fine, then change `classpathref` to `refid`

Comment: How do I echo classpath for Ant?

Comment: `<echo message="Classpath = ${myclasspath}"/>`

Comment: Sorry, all I get is the same exact message : "Classpath = ${classpath}"?

Comment: It then means that the classpath is not set at all. Check if you can echo atleast the value of `${lib.dir}` of your build.xml